# MVC Cascading Dropdownlist using Stored Procedures to populate Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, cascadingdropdown

So I have two dropdownlists, the second dropdown is dependent on the first one, hence the cascading style requirement. I have the first dropdownlist populated through a stored procedure but I'm unsure how to pass the ID value of the first dropdown to a stored procedure in order to populate the second drop down. I have the stored procedure for the second dropdown set up, but unsure how to call it within the controller with having the SelectedValue of the first dropdown being passed in as a parameter. Here's my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateForm(){
        List<SelectListItem> CountyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> DistrictList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.USP_SELECT_COUNTY", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    CountyList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = rdr[0].ToString(),
                        Text = rdr[1].ToString()
                    });

                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.CountyList = new SelectList(CountyList.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TogetDistrictList(string CountyList)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> DistrictList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@IDN_COUNTY", CountyList) };
            SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand("dbo.USP_SELECT_DISTRICT", parameters, con);
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.USP_SELECT_DISTRICT", con))
            {

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    DistrictList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = rdr[0].ToString(),
                        Text = rdr[1].ToString()
                    });

                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.DistrictList = new SelectList(DistrictList.ToList(), "Value", "Text");


        //DistrictList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DistrictList1" + CountyList, Value = "DistrictList1" + CountyList });

        return Json(CountyList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public SqlCommand CreateCommand(string procedurename, SqlParameter[] parameters, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedurename, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
        {
            if (param.Value == null)
                param.Value = DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        return cmd;
    }

}
```

View:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  $('#ddlCounty').change(function () {$.ajax('@Url.Action("TogetDistrictList")',  JSON.stringify({CountyList: $("#ddlCounty").val()}) ).done(function(data){                        

                     $('#ddlDistrict').empty();
                     $.each(data,function(i,value){                      
                         $('#ddlDistrict').append($('<option/>').val(value.Value).text(value.Text))
                     })
                 });
                 });
});
</script>
```

```html
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCounty", ViewBag.CountyList as SelectList})

@Html.DropDownList("ddlDistrict", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())
```

With the above code, I get a NullReferenceException while debugging, I think it's because the selected dropdown value is being passed as NULL to the stored procedure but I'm not sure how to get around it as I tried putting in an actual ID value instead and still get the same error.

Comment: That is awful code for many reasons. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to code cascading dropdownlists

Comment: Appreciate the Fiddle, it's my first time populating cascading dropdowns from stored procedures, hence the code is all over the place. I'll take a look to get ideas on how to clean up my code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the Json.stringify to 
`data: ({CountyList: $('#ddlCountyList').val()}), datatype: json,`

This worked in passing the parent dropdown selected value to the controller action, which in turn populates the second dropdownlist.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not in the question. I have rolled back you edit. Edit this to include your answer.

Comment: Answer included.

Answer (score 0):

function GetDistrictList() {

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("TogetDistrictList", "getDistrict")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { CountyList: $('#countryId').val() },
            success: function(datas, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (datas != null) {
                    row = "";
                    row += "<option value='0'>--Select District---</option>";
                    $.each(datas,
                        function(i, v) {
                            row += "<option value='" + v.Value + "'>" + v.Text + "</option>";
                        })
                    $('#ddlDistrict').html(row);
                }
            },
            error: function(ex) {

            }
        });
    }
```